# matlab discrete wavelet transform wfastmod in wmulden

Tags: matlab, haar-wavelet, wavelet-transform

I am interested to derive the discrete wavelet transform for noise reduction of more than 50,000 data points. I am using wmulden - matlab tool for wavelet tranform. Under this function, wfastmcd, an another function is being called which takes only 50000 data points at a time. It would be highly helpful if anyone suggests how to partition the data point to get the transform of entire data set or if there is any other matlab tool available for these kind of calculations.

Comment: Consider reading [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to get best possible answers

Comment: In my MATLAB there is no `wfastmod`, do you mean `wfastmcd`?

Comment: Yes it is wfastmcd !

Comment: @MatthiasW. Do you have any idea about this function?

Comment: @Mambo: not yet, sorry. Just tried to get help/ documentation about your function and thought about reformatting your post with `code tags`.

Comment: Maybe you can solve your problem with the answer I provided?

Answer (score 1):

I've used a `for` loop to solve that one.

First of all, I've calculated how many "steps" I needed to take on my signal, on a fixed size window of 50000, like:

```
MAX_SAMPLES = 50000;
% mySignalSize is the size of my samples vector.
steps = ceil(mySignalSize/MAX_SAMPLES);
```

After that, I've applied the `wmulden` function "steps" times, checking every time if my step is not larger than the original signal vector size, like the following:

```
% Wavelet fields
level = 5;
wname = 'sym4';
tptr  = 'sqtwolog';
sorh  = 's';

npc_app = 'heur';
npc_fin = 'heur';

den_signal = zeros(mySignalSize,1);

for i=1:steps

    if (i*MAX_SAMPLES) <= mySignalSize
       x_den = wmulden(originalSignal( (((i-1) * MAX_SAMPLES) + 1) : (i*MAX_SAMPLES) ), level, wname, npc_app, npc_fin, tptr, sorh);
       den_signal((((i-1) * MAX_SAMPLES) + 1):i*MAX_SAMPLES) = x_den;
    else
        old_step = (((i-1) * MAX_SAMPLES) + 1);
        new_step = mySignalSize - old_step;
        last_step = old_step + new_step;
        x_den = wmulden(originalSignal( (((i-1) * MAX_SAMPLES) + 1) : last_step ), level, wname, npc_app, npc_fin, tptr, sorh);
        den_signal((((i-1) * MAX_SAMPLES) + 1):last_step) = x_den;
    end
end
```

That should do the trick.

Comment: i thing you should concatenate the `x_den` variables instead of replace them in every iteration...